# How to insert a collection of pojo objects in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, pojo, dynamodb-queries

How can I insert a List of pojo objects to DynamoDB?

```
public class MobileDevice {
  private String name;
  private String category;
  private List<Sensor> allSensors;
  
  //getters & setters
}

public class Sensor {
   private String sensorName;
   private String sensorId;
   private int millis;
}
```

In this example I want to insert an instance of MobileDevice to DynamoDB. Is there any way to do it without traversing all attributes. The difficulty is mainly with allSensors variable.

So far I was inserting items like this.

```
public void addDevice(MobileDevice device) {
        devicesTable.putItem(
                    new Item()
                            .withPrimaryKey("Name", device.getName())
                            .withString("Category", device.getCategory()));
    
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to be able to index the sensors? If not, is there a particular reason not to use the automatic mapper?

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic automatic mapper?

Answer (score 0):

you can use aws-java-sdk-dynamodb library.

Maven dependency -

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.952</version>
    </dependency>
```

create dynamodb client like below :-

```
public DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper() {
    return new DynamoDBMapper(buildAmazonDynamoDB(), dynamoDBMapperConfig());
}
private DynamoDBMapperConfig dynamoDBMapperConfig() {
    return DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder()
            .withSaveBehavior(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.CLOBBER)
            .withConsistentReads(DynamoDBMapperConfig.ConsistentReads.CONSISTENT)
            .withPaginationLoadingStrategy(DynamoDBMapperConfig.PaginationLoadingStrategy.EAGER_LOADING)
            .build();
}


private AmazonDynamoDB buildAmazonDynamoDB() {
    return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(
                    new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                            serviceEndpoint,
                            signingRegion
                    )
            )
            .withCredentials(
                    new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                            new BasicAWSCredentials(
                                    accessKey,
                                    secretKey
                            )
                    )
            )
            .build();
}
```

To save List of Items use:-

```
List<MobileDevice> list;
dynamoDBMapper().batchSave(list);
```

Comment: "I want to insert an instance of MobileDevice to DynamoDB"

Comment: to save a single item (instance in java term) u can do  dynamoDBMapper().save(<objectInstance>);